# How to convert strings in for loop to Pandas DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm collecting some data from a website to create a map.  I have some strings (latitude and longitude) inside a for loop as follows.  Once I get this figured out, I'll be adding other information to the DataFrame.

28.5455
66.91390228
59.01139831542969 
44.451599
38.55390167
35.2804985046
34.2961998
39.1754

I'm trying to convert this to a Pandas DataFrame, but when I do that, all the indexes are 0 instead of 0,1,2...

```
for row in csvread:
icao = row[0]
name = row[1]
latitude = row[2]
longitude = row[3]
metar_link = 'https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar/data?ids=' + icao + '&format=decoded&date=&hours=0'
page = requests.get(metar_link)
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')

if soup.select_one('td:contains("Text:") + td').text == 'No data found' or not 'SM' in (
        soup.select_one('td:contains("Text:") + td').text):
    #print(icao, 'no metars available for this airport!')
    continue

metar = soup.select_one('td:contains("Text:") + td').text
metar_data = func.fraction(metar)
visibility = float(func.convert_to_float(metar_data))
ceiling = func.convert_ceiling(metar)
flight_conditions = func.flight_conditions(ceiling, visibility)
color = func.colorize(flight_conditions)

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'lat': [latitude],
    'lon': [longitude]
})

print(data)
```

When I print data, I'm getting:

```
       lat         lon
0  28.5455  -81.332901
           lat          lon
0  66.91390228  -151.529007
           lat           lon
0  65.99279785  -153.7039948
           lat           lon
0  59.75439835  -154.9109955
                 lat                  lon
0  59.01139831542969  -161.82000732421875
         lat         lon
0  44.451599  -83.394096
           lat           lon
0  38.55390167  -121.2979965
             lat             lon
0  35.2804985046  -116.629997253
          lat           lon
0  34.2961998  -116.1620026
       lat         lon
0  39.1754  -76.668297
```

The problem is all the index are 0, they're supposed to increment by 1.  How can I fix this?

Comment: I looked at some examples for Pandas DataFrame, but all the ones I could find, they have the values manually entered in.  I'm trying to pass the values from the for loop into a DataFrame.  I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: https://python-graph-gallery.com/312-add-markers-on-folium-map/                                   This is what I'm trying to achieve, but I need to fix the DatFrame first.

Comment: Please fix indentation as code is not compilable in Python as it stands. I would edit but do not want to make assumptions on syntax.

Comment: @ansev, sorry I don't think I fully understand.  I'm new to Python and Pandas.  This is what I have now                                                                                                                               data = pd.DataFrame({
        'lat': [latitude],
        'lon': [longitude]
    })
    #data = data.reindex(list(range(0, len(data), 1)))
    data.index = range(len(data))
    print(data)

Comment: @MattDamoz ... before anything, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58435444/edit) your post for incorrect identation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refrain from building data frame inside a loop. Instead, collect all needed values in list or dictionary and then bind to a data frame once outside the loop. Right now, you appear to be printing one-row data frames inside the loop, so would only show 0-index.

Specifically, build a dictionary of all needed values inside loop and then bind in `DataFrame` constructor once outside loop. Below assumes all values you scrape from `BeautifulSoup` and process with `func` are scalars (not iterables of multiple values):

```
data_list = []

for row in csvread:
   icao, name, latitude, longitude = row[0:3]

   metar_link = ('https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar/data?ids=' + icao + 
                 '&format=decoded&date=&hours=0')

   page = requests.get(metar_link)
   soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')

   if soup.select_one('td:contains("Text:") + td').text == 'No data found' \
       or not 'SM' in (soup.select_one('td:contains("Text:") + td').text):
       #print(icao, 'no metars available for this airport!')
       continue

   # ASSUMED ALL VALUES BELOW ARE SCALARS
   metar = soup.select_one('td:contains("Text:") + td').text
   metar_data = func.fraction(metar)
   visibility = float(func.convert_to_float(metar_data))
   ceiling = func.convert_ceiling(metar)
   flight_conditions = func.flight_conditions(ceiling, visibility)
   color = func.colorize(flight_conditions)

   # APPEND DICTIONARY TO LIST (INSIDE LOOP)
   data_list.append({'icao': icao, 'name': name, 'latitude': latitude, 
                     'longitude': longitude, 'metar': metar, 
                     'metar_data': metar_data, 'visibility': visibility,
                     'flight_conditions': flight_conditions, 'color': color})

# BIND LIST OF DICTS (OUTSIDE LOOP)
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
```

Comment: thank you, that worked for me.  I'm getting 0,1,2.....  Now I just need to figure out the folium.CircleMarker() to add those to the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
data=data.reindex(list(range(0,len(df),1)))
```

Comment: data = pd.DataFrame({
        'lat': [latitude],
        'lon': [longitude]
    })
    data = data.reindex(list(range(0, len(data), 1)))
    print(data)                                                                                                                                  I tried that and I'm getting the same results as above, all the indexes are 0